# Fragments with multiple usage

Tags: android, fragment, android-recyclerview

Is it good practice to use a single `Fragment` with `RecyclerView` to display different data (Image with title or Image with title and description or only a  title) using a different `CustomAdapter` and a different `custom_item_view`?

Or is it better to create a `Fragment` for each different type of data??

Comment: that's way too broad... it depends of what you want to show/do. Some info is better to show in list, some others take the all fragments, etc. You should google some good UX examples to understand better how Android UX works

Comment: Thank you @MarianoZorrilla I am using `DrawerLayout` contains some items and `FrameLayout` to display the data of the selected item.

Nearly all items display list of data.Some show only some text, others show Image and title and the rest display Image ,title and Description depending on  `ArrayList<Item>` passed to `CustomAdapter` I created.

So the only usage of `Fragment` is passing the data to the `CustomAdapter`.

My question, Is it good to use the same `Fragment` to do this, or should I create multiple `Fragment` for the Three different data architecture??!!

Answer (score 1):

As Mariano says, it depends.

If the data is very similar, almost the same, you can use one Fragment. The problem with that is that as your app develops, the differences increase, and you get one Fragment with a lot of code that handles different types of data. The latter is an "anti pattern": it's something that happens often and is bad for code maintainability and testing.

I advise to use different Fragments, until your app has grown more or less stable, then determine if the Fragments are really almost the same, and if needed put them together.

Comment: I have 3 `CustomAdapter` an 3 different data types `ArrayList` is passed to the `Fragment` with data and it pass it to the suitable `CustomAdapter`.Your answer was helpful for me .Thank you

Comment: I'm happy I could be of help. Stackoverflow is your friend :-)

Answer (score 1):

I have same needs (DrawerLayout, fragments and so on..) and for my purpose I choose to create more fragments; before all the code is more readable and you can easily change a part or if you want you can rewrite a fragment with less problems. Bye.

Comment: Thank you @Nice for your answer, It was helpful.
But I am trying to make reusable code.